# How to perform conditional addition of columns in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataset. And I want to add the salary of each emp depending upon the months emp_worked.For ex as shown in below dataset emp with name 'aaa' worked for 4 months So I want to do addition of columns jan to Apr and stored it in Total_ sal column.

```
`import pandas as pd`

    data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\py\\p1.txt",delimiter=',')
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)



  emp_id emp_name  months_worked  total_sal   jan  feb      mar  apr  may  \
0       1      aaa              4        NaN  2000    1      2.0    3  4.0   
1       2      bbb              3        NaN     1    2      NaN    4  5.0   
2       3      bbb              7        NaN     1    2  34343.0    4  NaN   
3       4      bbb             12        NaN     1    2  33434.0    4  5.0   

      jun  jul      aug   sep   oct      nov   dec  
0  5555.0  NaN  74343.0     8     9     10.0   NaN  
1   643.0  7.0      NaN  9343    10  13431.0  12.0  
2  6343.0  7.0      NaN     9  1043     11.0  12.0  
3     NaN  7.0      8.0     9     1      NaN  12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Corrected the misalignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get the index where jan starts
months_index_start = df.columns.get_loc("jan")
# Calculate the total salary for each row according to the months_worked column
df["total_sal"] = df.apply(lambda x : x[months_index_start : months_index_start + x["months_worked"]].sum(), axis = 1)
```

Comment: I tried the solution provided by you .but getting below error .TypeError: ("cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [4] of <class 'int'>", 'occurred at index 1')

Comment: @Saurabh, try df = df.reset_index() before.

Comment: I tried but giving the same error mentioned above:(

Comment: Today I tried same solution and surprisingly it work for me.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Total_sal'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.get_loc('jan'):df.columns.get_loc('apr')]].sum(axis=1)
```

out:

```
    emp_id  emp_name    months_worked   total_sal   jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec Total_sal
1   aaa 4   NaN 2000    1   2.0 3   4.0 5555.0  NaN 74343.0 8   9   10.0    NaN 12.0    6.0
2   bbb 3   NaN 1   2   NaN 4   5.0 643.0   7.0 NaN 9343    10  13431.0 12.0    NaN 6.0
3   bbb 7   NaN 1   2   34343.0 4   NaN 6343.0  7.0 NaN 9   1043    11.0    12.0    NaN 34349.0
4   bbb 12  NaN 1   2   33434.0 4   5.0 NaN 7.0 8.0 9   1   NaN 12.0    NaN 33440.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply But above solution is always taking months from jan to Apr for every row. What I want to accomplish is depending upon the months_worked value I need to calculate the total_sal for each row in dataset
For ex
1.For emp_id=1 months_worked=4 total_sal=2010

2.For emp_id=2 months_worked=3 total_sal=3

3.For emp_id=3 months_worked=7 total_sal=40700

4.For emp_id=4 months_worked=12 total_sal=33483

Comment: we can use df[df.columns[-12:]].sum(axis =1) . which can give the summation  of all row values of months. But we need list of month names on which he worked for, so we can make condition to add respective months data :-)

Comment: Is there any other python library through which we can do this. I stuck on getting the summation of salary based on the value of months_worked?

Comment: we can do that with the summation function w.r.t  months worked, but if 4 months_worked for one emp_id, which columns of month names should we add. please mention either start from one month or some criteria